# Bootstrap 4 - How do I right justify something in the footer?

Tags: bootstrap-4

Note: Bootstrap **4**.

I have the following footer (some irrelevant ASP stuff left in):

```
<footer class="footer bg-light">
    <span class="footer-copyright">
        &copy; @DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().Year - @ApplicationResources.CompanyName
    </span>
    <span>
        @ApplicationResources.Versions: @ApplicationResources.Web @appsettings.WebVersion / @ApplicationResources.Api @appsettings.ApiVersion
    </span>
</footer>
```

The copyright is left justified (as I want), but I cannot work out how to right justify the Version details (which I want).  If I make the spans, divs and then use "text-right", it works, but appears on the line below the copyright, making the footer taller (don't want).  "text-right" has no effect on the spans.

I cannot find a single example on the web.

One other thing.  Some footer examples I have found have a "page-footer" class on the footer element, rather than just "footer".  If I do that, then the footer is no longer stuck to the bottom of the page.

**How do I right-justify the version information on the same line as the copyright?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox and the [justify content helpers](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/#justify-content) from Bootstrap by adding `d-flex` and `justify-content-between` class names to the footer:

```html
<footer class="footer bg-light d-flex justify-content-between">
    <div class="footer-copyright">
        &copy; @DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().Year - @ApplicationResources.CompanyName
    </div>
    <div>
        @ApplicationResources.Versions: @ApplicationResources.Web @appsettings.WebVersion / @ApplicationResources.Api @appsettings.ApiVersion
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: What a star!  I would never have found that.  Ross, thank you for the quick reply.  Marked as answer (well in 7 mins I can).

Comment: That flexbox utility page is great, I use those Bootstrap utility classes all the time. Glad it worked for you.